# Where to initialize an instance variable in a class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to objective-c and I always have problem with global variable . I don't know where to initialize them . My problem is with an NSString . I wrote this code –

in .h

```
NSString *session ; // i also  @property(retain,nonatomic) and synthesize ...
```

in `viewDidLoad` ,  '

```
session=@"HEllo";
```

and in

```
-(IBAction) showInformations:(id)sender;
{
    NSLog(@" informations ok");
    NSLog(@"my sesison : %@  ",session);
}
```

But I have a crash in show information :/ session is empty I think . Help please

Comment: Are you sure that `session=@"HEllo";` is the **real** code? And the only part of the code that saves something in the `session` variable? Sounds like you haven't retained the value properly.

Comment: Frankly I don't think there is any problem with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session = @"hello";
self.session = @"hello";
```

There is a huge difference between the above two statements. The first one just assigns `hello` to `session`. Here the string `hello` is autoreleased, so `session` is not valid when you tap the button, as you have not retained `session`. But in 2nd line `self` is used. When `self` is used, it is not just a simple assignment, it is actually a call to accessor method. Here you have used `retain` in property declaration. So when `self` is used, the setter for `session` is called which retains it. So `session` is valid when you tap the button.

The summery is use right property and use `self` to avoid many memory problems.

EDIT: As pointed by fluchtpunkt, this explanation is not valid for string literals. I was out of my mind that string literals are special when writing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it using the dot syntax for a property:

```
self.session=@“Hello”;
```

This will ensure proper memory management.

Answer (score 0):

There must be another write access to session somewhere in your code. A line of code that looks like `session = [NSString stringWith...];`

So find the other parts of the code where you assign something to the `session` variable and replace the wrong memory management over there with proper memory management. The problem is not within the three lines you have shown.

Depending on your code it should be something like

```
self.session = [NSString stringWith...
```

or if you like it inconvenient

```
[session release];
session = [[NSString stringWith...] retain];
```

Comment: The problem is in session = @"hello" in viewDidLoad as setter is not called there. Check the comment of OP on my and johnnieb's answer.

Comment: this is not the problem. There is no need to retain string literals like @"hello". String literals get never released and because of this they also get never deallocated. I bet $10 that the OP didn't post the real code. And he just used the self.session change on his autoreleased string object. That's why it is working for him.

Comment: I see your point. But can't test this now as I don't have a Mac right now.

Comment: No need to test anything. fluchtpunkt is correct, @"" constant strings do not need to be retained. Strings created with convenience methods and macros like NSLocalizedString do, however.